# How would a world in which there are intellectual nations function?

Tags: technology, government, internet

#### In a world where the ideas of intellectual property are expanded beyond simply owning an idea to everything else, how would society function?

In this world, the idea that government's primary role is to protect people's property. With the rise of the internet and the importance of intellectual property, many began to believe that standard physical governments weren't properly protecting their intellectual property.

So, many online *governments* began to spring up. Their primary concern is the protection of intellectual property, and they do not concern themselves with physical things. As a result everyone that is a *citizen* of one of these online groups must also be a citizen of a real country as well.

**My questions are: how would these *governments* change the world from now, how could these *governments* gain power (needing to be given it by its citizens and other governments of the world), and how would real countries react to this new idea of citizenship?**

Comment: *How* do these "online governments" protect intellectual property? The only ways to do this on the internet is by threatening physical repercussions through the legal system of the physical world, and that's what "offline" governments are for.

Comment: @Philipp There would be some kind of punishment, although I do not think they'd be forced to delve into physical repercussions. Obviously there would be some would be some form of social contract, giving the government some power over you (even if it's just your online self) in return for protection.

Comment: You say "real countries."  Is that wording just used for our benefit, clarifying meaning in common terms, or do you believe these new governments are second class entities, overshadowed by the physical nations?

Comment: @CortAmmon It was meant as clarification. Although at least at the beginning, there's no way any "real countries" would recognize the authority or legitimacy of the "intellectual countries."

Answer (score 2):

I could already name two such emerging "internet governments": Facebook and Google.

Information is power. Many people receive their information from online services. By manipulating who sees which information (and [they already do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble)), they can influence people:

- They could decide elections by deciding which news to suppress and which news to spread.
- They could make companies big with their advertisement services.
- They could destroy companies whose business models relies on their service. [Like this poor guy on programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289460/the-critical-functionality-of-an-api-has-changed-what-should-i-do).
- They could enforce social norms and ethics through their allowed content policies. *Picture of people having sex? Banned. Picture of people kissing? Ok. Picture of **gay** people kissing? Hmmm...*
- They could destroy individual people through all the personal information they have about them. Politician X has stupid ideas about regulating online services? Time to leak that cellphone picture of him doing coke from the butt of a prostitute.
- They could even decide wars by inferring military secrets with their massive data-mining capabilities and providing the preferred side with that information. Case in point: [The drone strike app](http://uk.businessinsider.com/apple-bans-drone-strike-app-from-app-store-2015-9?op=1&IR=T).

By expanding into more and more business sectors, they could become so important for the life of the individual citizen that not using them becomes impossible. You might currently only use [Service] for keeping in contact with your friends. Imagine you also need [Service] to pay your bills, shop for groceries, do your day-to-day job and dealing with government authorities. Imagine you get banned from [Service] for violating their TOS (you shouldn't have posted that evil pro net neutrality propaganda). This would destroy your life. So you better stay in line and be a good citizen of [Service]. Welcome to 1984.

Currently the biggest factor which hinders these service from gaining that much power is anonymity. Because it is currently not easily possible to identify individual people on the internet, people can keep using their services even after they got banned by creating a new identity. But getting rid of anonymity on the internet is currently a dream of law enforcement, security agencies and companies alike. When any person of the planet would have one (and only one) personal and unchangeable "internet ID", no internet access is possible without one and every connection could be linked to the person, that obstacle would be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think this idea would be tragic, especially in the world of today, where everything is controlled via the internet.

The government could easily steal intellectual property and hide any evidence of doing so as is possible on the internet, which is an example of a thing that could go wrong.

Society would run differently, more people would spend their lives on the internet neglecting the physical world, it might even go on to the point where mass funding is put into bringing human physical self into the internet.

The government would gain power from holding information about people and also governing their online property like identities, details, history, money, etc. much the same as the physical government would.

Comment: tl;dr: nothing changes :)

Answer (score 0):

A cloud computing company could evolve into such a nation. Within cloud-nation different companies could have API that can only accessed from within the cloud-nation. The cloud nation could add conflict arbitration to their roles.

Comment: This is a good start for an answer, but I think it would be possible to expand much further on this concept.